# How choose random number within range, but weighted toward one part of that range? (in Java)

Tags: java, random, apache-commons

I want to choose random numbers within a range of numbers, but with weighting towards part of that range. For example:

1. Choose random number between 1-10
2. Weight it so that 1-5 is maybe 20% more likely than 6-10

Is this possible? How would I do this?

Comment: Do you want 1 to be the most likely and 10 to be least likely, or you you want 1-5 to be equally likely and 6-10 to be equally likely?

Comment: I play all sorts of dice games.  I have never considered this question.  So +1 for you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on how you want your probability distribution to look like.

For example:

```
Pick a random number between 1-10
If it is <= 6
    Return a random number between 1-5
Else
    Return a random number between 6-10
EndIf
```

Picks a number in 1-5 60% of the time and a number in 6-10 40% of the time.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing! Since it works, and you posted it before I did, I'm marking this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To generate a bell curve of probabilities, roll and sum multiple dice.  Then subtract the average. Re-roll if the result is negative.  The more dice rolled, the more weighting.

Here's one way, wholly untested.

```
float sum;
do {
   sum = rollThreeDice(); // returns 3 to 18, with an average is 10.5
   sum -= 10.5;           // Now the range is 0 to 7.5, with the lower end being more likely.
   } while(sum < 0);
return sum;
```

Of course you can roll dice with any number of sides in order to produce the desired range.  You control the frequency curve by choosing the number of dice.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions come to mind. First, run a random twice:

```
java.utils.Random randomGenerator = new java.utils.Random();
int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(11);
if(random <= 6) { //This is 20% more
    random = randomGenerator.nextInt(5) + 1;
} else {
    random = randomGenerator.nextInt(5) + 6;
}
```

Or if you always have a static range, you could fill an array with the numbers, adding more of the numbers you want more of and choose a random over the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public int weightedRandom() {
  int rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1) // From 1 to 5
  if (Math.random() >= 0.6) {
    ++rand;
  }
  return rand;
}
```